# how to edit source code in JAR file and combine it again?

Tags: java

I have extract the JAR file with winrar, and i able to saw all the class file which inside the JAR file.

I wish to edit some of the source code for the entire JAR file, and combine it again become a new JAR file which can work properly.
I have successful to edit the source code in class file, how can i combine it again??

is it i need to create a new project? copy all the source code in class file to a java file?
i have no idea and i am still new to this.
thanks if got any comment or better solution.

Comment: Did the jar come with the source or did you decompile it?

Comment: ya i had decompile it, and i saw all the source code in class file. what should i do for next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your Freind : "Java create a jar"

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html